# How can I get a Google Apps Script Web App to call itself back?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've built a web app in Google Apps Script with a Signup.html page and a Code.gs page. It is for students signing up for different parts of our school library. When I built this a couple of years ago before Google changed the Web App Console, I used hidden DIV's to give the user a way back to the app after a form was submitted. On Submission, one div would hide, and another Div would show saying "Submission complete, click here to continue" with a link to the back to the web app. When clicked, it would show the student what they signed up for and offer additional signup or cancellation options.

With the new Versioned Apps (well, new for me) I am stuck in a cycle. I deploy the web app, get a new link for it, paste it back into my HTML file, run my code, and the file has the last deployment's link in it. When clicked, it errors out (because I have archived the previous deployment).

How can I save a deployment with the correct "current" link in the HTML without redeploying and getting a new link? Or, is there a better way to get the user back to the form after submission?

Thank you,

Allan

Comment: Try: UrlFetchApp.fetch(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl());

Comment: Thank you Cooper. I am struggling a bit. I added that into Code.gs doGet(e) as temp.uri = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl());
return temp.evaluate();    Then in the HTML I attempted to display it with <?= uri; ?> and the page errored with "Page Not Found." Is something off in my syntax?

Comment: I would need to see more of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

> If there's anything that has been misunderstood, please feel free to let me know.

Based on your post, I understand that you have the following workflow:

1. Deploy the web app.
2. Manually obtain a new web app link.
3. Insert the link into your HTML file's source code.
4. Run your web app.
5. Click the manually added web app link on the HTML page.

I agree with @Cooper's suggestion to use the [`getUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#geturl) method, as it returns the most up-to-date URL of the web app after deployment. You may try this approach below as it is superior to manually specifying the actual URL of the web app. You can refer to the sample script for guidance on how to implement this approach and use it as a reference in your actual project.

***HTML file*** *(`SignUp.html`)* *[UPDATED]*

> This sample utilizes the `getUrl` method from the Apps Script & passes it to the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">

<body>
  TESTING
  <br><br>
  Click <a href=<?=webAppUrl ?>><?= sch ?></a> HERE
</body>

</html>
```

***GS file*** *[UPDATED]*

```
function doGet() {
  var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SignUp');
  let school = "TEST SCHOOL NAME";
  let url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  temp.sch = school;
  temp.webAppUrl = url;
  return temp.evaluate();
}
```

### *Quick Demo*

[image]

### *References*

- [`getUrl` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#geturl)

Comment: Thank you @SputnikDrunk2

I am not longer getting an error on page load but the link is incorrect once clicked.

My call to the Signup Page is a little different than what you had and I am not sure if that is the cause?

on doGet(e)
// yours return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
//mine
var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SignUp');


because I am using the temp variable further down to pass data back to the signup page

Comment: Thanks @SputnikDrunk2

I am not longer getting an error on page load but the link is incorrect once clicked. My call to the Signup Page is a little different than what you had and I am not sure if that is the cause?

on doGet(e)
// yours return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');

//mine
var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SignUp');


because I am using the temp variable further down to pass data back to the signup page like this:
SignUp.html
.innerHTML = 'Click <a href="' + url + '?sch=<?= sch; ?>">HERE</a>';

temp.sch = school;
return temp.evaluate();

Comment: This is noted. I have updated the script answer. You may use it as a reference on your actual project. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @SputnikDrunk2. The app still is not giving the correct URL. I currently have only one active Deployment. When I load this, AKfycbzpBbjlHSJvsxpb4RG3fJElISuXhj7FAVA8VnuqZ461lqw7QhHfySS7Q0jRyQmpxPyD/exec?school=562, and execute, the resulting link back is AKfycbzlYIIojm9X58AZK4geOgvViTtTzFSigomYA4X7jklpgGOZ738/exec?school=562. No matter how many times I deploy, it is always the same link. I have confirmed that this not the Head Deployment.

Comment: I can't replicate your behaviour in my test script. `getUrl()` consistently returns the latest deployed URL. Since this seems specific to your actual project's `getUrl()`, consider creating a new post with an identical script for replication. This will help address new issues distinctly. Check out [Creating a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks @SputnikDrunk2. I started to  do what you asked and in the process made a copy of my spreadsheet and deployed the attached code. I am not sure why, but everything on the copy is working as you designed it. Thank you so much! Your help is greatly appreciated!